# Showing that $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are conjugate iff $\chi(g)$ is real

Tags: representation-theory

I am trying to show that for a finite group $G$ and $g\in G$,  $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are conjugate iff $\chi(g)$ is real for all $\chi$  irreducible characters of $G$. I have the following:

I first want to show that $\chi(g^{-1})=\overline{\chi(g)}$. Now if we have $\chi(g)=\sum \lambda_i$ with the $\lambda_i$ being roots of unity (as o(g) is finite) then we have:

$\overline{\chi(g)}=\overline{\sum \lambda_i}=\sum\overline{\lambda_i}=\sum{\lambda_i^{-1}=}\chi(g^{-1})$ as desired.

Now we have that if $\chi(g)$ is real then $\chi(g)=\chi(g^{-1})$ hence they are in the same conjugacy class.

Now if we assume that $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are conjugate then we have that $\exists h\in G$ such that $h^{-1}g^{-1}h=g$. But then $\chi(h^{-1}g^{-1}h)=\chi(g^{-1})$, by considering traces of conjugate matrices and so $\chi(g^{-1})=\chi(g)$ and so must be real from above.

Is everything I have done ok?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You need to be careful with the statement. "Where $\chi$ is an irreducible complex character" makes it incorrect. It should be "for all irreducible complex characters".

Comment: Looks fine but a little lengthy: pay attention to the fact that $\;\chi(g)\in S^1\subset\Bbb C\iff \overline{\chi(g)}=\chi(g)^{-1}\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: $\overline{\chi(g)}$ is not typically equal to $\chi(g)^{-1}$. For instance, $\chi(1) = \overline{\chi(1)}$ can be any positive integer, and the only integer equal to its multiplicative inverse is 1.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Note $\chi(g) \in S^1$

Comment: Are you serious? $2 \notin S^1$

Comment: That is true now that you mention it, @JackSchmidt: for some reason, and because of the same notation, I was thinking of a representation of a *finite* group into the multiplicative subgroup of the complex...Thanks.

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3991679/prove-that-the-number-of-real-conjugacy-classes-in-g-is-equal-to-the-number-of