# Prove that the number of real conjugacy classes in $G$ is equal to the number of irreducible real characters

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group.

A conjugacy class $g^G$ of $G$ is called a **real conjugacy class** if $g$ is conjugate to $g^{-1}$.

A character $\chi$ of $G$ is called **real** if $\chi (g) \in \Bbb R$ for all $g \in G$.

By considering $ \{ f: G \to \Bbb C : f(g) = f(h^{-1}gh) = f(g^{-1}),  \forall g,h \in G \} $, prove that the number of real conjugacy classes in $G$ is equal to the number of irreducible real characters.

I don't know how to do this, nor how to start with the suggested method. An answer would be appreciated.

Comment: There is an involution $X \mapsto X^{-1}$ taking a conjugacy class to its inverse: the self-inverse conjugacy classes are the fixed points of this map. There is also an involution $\chi \mapsto \overline{\chi}$ taking an irreducible complex character to its complex conjugate: the real-valued characters are the fixed points of this map. Now consider the vector space of class functions, and define the $\mathbb{C}$-linear involution $f \mapsto f^*$, where $f^*(g) = f(g^{-1})$. You can look at the 1-eigenspace ($f^* = f$) and $(-1)$-eigenspace ($f^* = -f$) of this map...

Comment: @Joppy I think that should be an answer.

Comment: Thank you! That does answer my question, I think

Comment: @runway44 It's not quite an answer, there is still a bit more to be done. The dimension of the $1$-eigenspace is larger than the number of real characters, since for each strictly complex character, $\chi + \chi^*$ is real and fixed under the involution, while $\chi - \chi^*$ is negated under the involution. So the dimension of the $(-1)$-eigenspace is half the number of strictly complex characters (or half the number of non-self-inverse conjugacy classes). This still yields the required equality, but it's slightly more complicated than my comment might have let on.

Comment: @Joppy i don’t understand, what should be the solution? The difficult fact is to prove that the number of real irreducible representations is exactly equal to the number of real conjugacy classes. You’ve just proved that is less or equal than, and it was clear

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is a consequence of the Brauer permutation lemma. Firstly, call $Irr(G)$ and $cl(G)$ for the set of all irreducible characters of $G$ and all $G$-conjugacy classes.

> Let $A$ be a group which acts con $Irr(G)$ and on $cl(G)$. Assume that $\chi^a(g^a)=\chi(g)$ for all $g \in G$ and $a \in A$. Then, for all $a \in A$, the number of $a$-fixed characters is equal to the number of $a$-fixed conjugacy classes.

This is Theorem 6.32 of Isaac's "Chatacter Theory of Finite Groups" or can be found in a more complex form (along several other useful results) in chapter 18 of Huppert's "Character Theory of Finite Groups".

Now, consider $A$ the group generated by $a$, a permutation that acts on $cl(G)$ inverting classes and on $Irr(G)$ as the complex conjugation. Since $\chi(g^{-1})=\overline\chi(G)$, we can easily check that $\chi^a(g^a)=\chi(g)$. The lemma above should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The two actions that represent swapping rows and columns are:

1. On rows sending the respective character $\chi$ to its conjugate: $\chi \mapsto \overline{\chi}$.
2. On columns sending the conjugacy class of $g$ to the conjugacy class of $g^{-1}$ i.e. $\mathrm{ccl}(g) \mapsto \mathrm{ccl}(g^{-1})$.

(This is a slight rephrasing of how you wrote it in the question, in my opinion this is a little clearer, but it is the same as what you wrote.)

Note the relationship $\overline{\chi}(g) = \chi(g^{-1})$. (Consider the eigenvalues of $\rho(g)$, $\rho(g^{-1})$ for $\rho$ the representation that affords $\chi$.)

Let $X$ be a matrix representing the character table. Then the actions correspond to left and right-multiplying by permutation matrices $A$, $B$ respectively, i.e $X \mapsto AX$, $X \mapsto XB$. The number of fixed points of a permutation corresponds to the trace of the permutation matrix, i.e. $\mathrm{tr} (A)$ is the number of fixed rows, $\mathrm{tr}( B)$ the number of fixed columns.

Note $X$ is invertible (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303806/invertibility-of-character-table#:%7E:text=The%20character%20table%20of%20a,with%20respect%20to%20%E2%9F%A8%20%2C%20%E2%9F%A9.)).

Thus, because of the stated relationship, $AX = XB$ i.e. $A = XBX^{-1}$.

So $\mathrm{tr}(A) = \mathrm{tr}(B)$. Hence the result.